# INNER JOIN 4 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

it's my first time here and my first question so sorry if i ask something stupid.
Well my problem is for MySQL. 
Let me explain

I have 4 tables (T1,T2,T3,T4)

T1 (t1_id,external_id) here i keep the id's from T2,T3,T4 and then i have
T2 (t2_id,name,etc...)
T3 (t3_id,name,etc...)
T4 (t4_id,name,etc...)

the T1 has already some entries from these tables.
T2,T3,T4 have nothing common beetwen them but T1 has cause it keeps their ID's.

so the query is

```
**SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.*, T4.*
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t2_id=T1.external_id
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.t2_id=T1.external_id
INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.t2_id=T1.external_id**
```

and it doesn't show nothing.I tried with LEFT JOIN but nothing.... but if i do this

```
**SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t2_id=T1.external_id**
```

it works and shows data.

I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: You say you tried this and no rows, is it correct?
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.*, T4.*
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.t2_id=T1.external_id
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.t2_id=T1.external_id
LEFT JOIN T4 ON T4.t2_id=T1.external_id

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.*, T4.*
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t2_id=T1.external_id
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.t3_id=T1.external_id
INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.t4_id=T1.external_id
```

Note that I have changed the id for T3 & T4, I assume that t2_id does not exist in them?

Comment: Alternately you can replace INNER JOIN with LEFT OUTER JOIN, which should retrieve all rows from T2,T3 and T4 which have a relationship on the id with T1.

Answer (score 0):

You should have three columns to hold each table id on T1.

> T1 (T1_id, T2_id, T3_id, T4_id)

So when you do the inner join would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.t2_id = T1.t2_id
INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.t3_id = T1.t3_id
INNER JOIN T4 ON T2.t4_id = T1.t4_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers i used LEFT JOIN and now it's working. But the problem was that it was a capital letter on my database and both INNER & LEFT was not working.

Inner isn't correct to use cause there isn't always an entry from t2,t3,t4.

Thank you again for your time and your support!